# В чём может быть причина что с одного устройства выполняется запрос на сервер, а на другом выдаёт ошибку

Tags: java, android

В общем такая проблема, пишу приложение в Android Studio делаю запрос к api в эмуляторе всё нормально подключается и получает ответ с сервера, но когда запускаю на реальном устройстве при попытке подключения к api с тем же запросом выдаётся ошибка java.io.FileNotFoundException.
Вот код класса для подключения к api:

```
package com.example.avtomoy;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ThreadRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    private String URL_API="https://*********/api";
    byte[] data = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    String resultString = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            switch (strings[0]){
                case "login":
                    URL_API+="/login";
                    break;
                case "forget-password":
                    URL_API+="/forget-password";
                    break;
                case "registration":
                    URL_API+="/registration";
                    break;
                case "my-cars-page":
                    URL_API+="/my-cars-page";
                    break;
                case "history-page":
                    URL_API+="/history-page";
                    break;
                case "get-services":
                    URL_API+="/get-services";
                    break;
                case "get-services2":
                    URL_API+="/get-services?carWashId="+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-add-services":
                    URL_API+="/get-add-services";
                    break;
                case "get-add-services2":
                    URL_API+="/get-add-services?carWashId="+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-time-and-price":
                    URL_API+="/get-time-and-price?services="+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-select-map-periods":
                    URL_API+="/get-select-map-periods?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-avaible-times":
                    URL_API+="/get-avaible-times?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-car-washes-by-filter":
                    URL_API+="/get-car-washes-by-filter?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "signup-car-wash":
                    URL_API+="/signup-car-wash";
                    break;
                case "carwash-contacts-page":
                    URL_API+="/carwash-contacts-page?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "carwash-contacts-page2":
                    URL_API+="/carwash-contacts-page";
                    break;
                case "chat-inbox-page":
                    URL_API+="/chat-inbox-page";
                    break;
                case "remove-transport":
                    URL_API+="/remove-transport";
                    break;
                case "add-transport":
                    URL_API+="/add-transport";
                    break;
                case "change-transport":
                    URL_API+="/change-transport";
                    break;
                case "carwash-sales-page":
                    URL_API+="/carwash-sales-page?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "is-free":
                    URL_API+="/is-free";
                    break;
                case "carwash-comfort-page":
                    URL_API+="/carwash-comfort-page?"+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "get-available-dates":
                    URL_API+="/get-available-dates?carWashId="+strings[2];
                    break;
                case "change-settings":
                    URL_API+="/change-settings";
                    break;
            }
            URL url = new URL(URL_API);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            if((strings[0].equals("my-cars-page"))||(strings[0].equals("history-page"))||(strings[0].equals("get-services2"))||(strings[0].equals("get-add-services2"))||(strings[0].equals("get-time-and-price"))||(strings[0].equals("get-select-map-periods"))||(strings[0].equals("get-avaible-times"))||(strings[0].equals("get-car-washes-by-filter"))||(strings[0].equals("carwash-contacts-page2"))||(strings[0].equals("chat-inbox-page"))||(strings[0].equals("is-free"))||(strings[0].equals("carwash-contacts-page"))||(strings[0].equals("carwash-sales-page"))||(strings[0].equals("carwash-comfort-page"))||(strings[0].equals("get-available-dates"))){

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + strings[1]);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" );
            }else {

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                if((strings[0].equals("get-services"))||(strings[0].equals("get-add-services"))||(strings[0].equals("signup-car-wash"))||(strings[0].equals("remove-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("add-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("change-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("change-settings"))){
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + strings[1]);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(strings[2].getBytes().length));

                }else {
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(strings[1].getBytes().length));
                }
            }
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            data = strings[1].getBytes("UTF-8");
            if((strings[0].equals("get-services"))||(strings[0].equals("get-add-services"))||(strings[0].equals("signup-car-wash"))||(strings[0].equals("remove-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("add-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("change-transport"))||(strings[0].equals("change-settings"))){
                data = strings[2].getBytes("UTF-8");
            }

            os.write(data);
            data = null;
            conn.connect();
            int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            data = baos.toByteArray();
            resultString = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            Log.i("MyLog",""+resultString);
            return resultString;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Может быть стоит какие-то настройки на устройстве посмотреть?

Comment: Попробуй Log закомментировать

Comment: Когда ищете решение вопроса с ошибкой, добавляйте ещё описание самой ошибки. Данное исключение говорит что вы не смогли получить доступ к файлу, которого скорее всего нет. Вы уверены что у вас ошибка происходит в этом обьекте? Опять же вопрос версии АПИ на устройстве и эмуляторе. Мб вам нужно получить разрешение на чтение/запись и т.д.

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов, Log убрал ситуация не изменилась

Comment: @Valeriy ошибка происходит вот в этой строке is = conn.getInputStream();, как я писал в вопросе в эмуляторе работает, сегодня тестировали на другом устройстве работает без ошибок, а на моём телефоне ошибка java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: И о чём это говорит? Вы поленились разобраться в проблеме и ваше устройство является проблемным, копайте в этом направлении, это раз! Два: вы опять максимально стараетесь утаивать факты которые не являются конфиденциальными, а именно устройство, на котором происходит сбой. Три: ставите бряку перед этой строкой, запускаете дебаг, смотрите что есть в "conn" и чем отличается от того же в эмуляторе, потом заныриваете в метод "getInputStream()" и смотрете чем он отличается на эмуляторе и у вас. Возможно в итоге вам прийдётся его или переписывать или искать друго е решение.